# How to mask ssh using obfsproxy?

Tags: linux, privacy, ssh, tor

How to obfuscate ssh connection using obfsproxy (obfs4proxy) ?

What is the configuration on Linux for obfs4proxy and openssh-server (ex. /etc/ssh/sshd_config) ? (server-side)

What is the configuration on Windows/Linux for obfs4proxy and powershell built-in ssh client ? How to use obfsproxy on Windows ? (client-side)

I want to access my openssh server (that I own) and bypass deep packet inspection at work.

Please give me a detailed answer, step by step for both sides (client and server).

Comment: Did you google this? https://crgm.net/2012/11/13/obfuscate-ssh-traffic-with-obfsproxy.html

Comment: "*Please give me a detailed answer*" bold ask for someone not showing [any research...](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)